# How to control multiple leds independently with arduino but they share a 12v external power source

Tags: led

I have a project with many components.  I'd like to use 12v adapter from wall.
I have a simplified experiment to apply to the actual project.  I can't find any info on the internet after days of searching.
I want to control each of 6 leds independently with an arduino. They all have different forward voltages.  But I would like them to be powered by the same 12v external power supply.  I suspect I would use transistors, Could someone point me in the right direction to wire these up?
I can figure out the code myself.

Comment: yes. use an N-channel MOSFET and ignore it when calculating resistors. google" mosfet as a swtich". The code you need is contained in the blink example.

Comment: Thanks.  That's simple!

Answer (score 2):

The basic schematic for one LED is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgvfg7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Make sure that:

- R1 is the right resistance for the supply voltage, forward voltage, and desired current
- M1 has a threshold low enough that the Arduino turns it fully on.

Just duplicate the circuit for each LED you want to control. The code is no different to having an LED directly attached to the Arduino.

Comment: Thanks! Very easy.  Obviously I'm a newbie.  So each led will be in parallel, right?

Comment: Not each LED, no. Each complete circuit.

Comment: Yeah, I meant circuit.  Thank you!